# Node.js BDD. Cucumber, gherkin, or cucumis?

Tags: node.js, cucumber, gherkin

I want to start using BDD for one of my Node.js projects. Looking at the Node.js wiki, I find at least 3 modules: [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js), [gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin), and [cucumis](https://github.com/noblesamurai/cucumis) that all support the gherkin language. Which ones do you recommend?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cucumber.js is the official port of Cucumber. It is supported by the Cucumber community and aims at being as compatible as possible with its brothers (Cucumber-ruby, Cucumber-jvm). It's strongly tested through the same gherkin feature suite as Cucumber-ruby and Cucumber-jvm.

Cucumber.js is supported in both Node.js and browser environments. It uses the official Gherkin parser, just like Cucumber-ruby.

I'm not really familiar with Cucumis but the only advantage of it over Cucumber.js is that it supports parallel scenario execution. We are considering such a feature on Cucumber.js but it needs some more thinking as it has implications end-users must fully understand.

The *gherkin* NPM package is not usable as is, it's only supplying the gherkin parser.

The Cucumber.js's [README](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) displays a development status table that can help you decide wether it's ready for your needs or not.

If you need support with Cucumber.js, shout in #cucumber on Freenode, ping [us on Twitter](http://twitter.com/cucumber_js) or write to the [Cukes list](https://groups.google.com/group/cukes).

If you're interested, Cucumber.js will be [presented](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/cucumber-js-cuke-up-your-javascript) during the [CukeUp! conference](http://cukes.info/cukeup.html) in London on April 4th.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: Using cucumber.js, can I generate junit style XML files?

Comment: There is no such formatters yet. But this can be added, given we have the XML schema available.

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at [Yadda](http://github.com/acuminous/yadda). It's a BDD framework with a Gherkin-like syntax (not 100% compatible) which piggybacks on your existing test runner (e.g. mocha, jasmine, casper, qunit). The reports are therefore formatted in the same way as your unit tests.